# Are questions about Google Maps Engine on-topic?

Tags: support, scope

[Google Maps Engine](https://mapsengine.google.com/map/) is used in websites to show locations. Though there is no actual programming for Google Maps Engine, it is still a tool. Just like [Sublime Text Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sublimetext) which has many answers.

So why are questions about Google Maps Engine being downvoted and tagged as "off topic." Even in the meta there was a lot of negative attitude from other developers. For example, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269499/why-is-this-question-about-google-maps-engine-being-voted-to-close

Comment: Sublime isn't just a tool. It's a "software tool commonly used by programmers" (from the help center). If you don't program **for** Google Maps Engine, and you don't program **in** Google Maps Engine (which you do in Sublime), then it's not really the same.

Comment: You can use Google Maps Engine without interacting with the API. And that is what the referenced question is about.

Comment: @derp, whoops, I see what you mean.  Sorry! :)

Answer (score 18):

You seem to be misunderstanding the tag. You're trying to categorize the topic "Google Maps Engine" as either entirely on-topic or entirely off-topic. That's simply not how the scope of our site works. A topic, even this one, has many different aspects to it. Some of those are on-topic here, others are not.

Browsing over the tag, a lot of the open questions doing well appear to be about accessing the Google Maps Engine API (definitely on-topic) or modifying the appearance of the map generated by Google Maps Engine via JavaScript (definitely on-topic).

Your specific question appears to be about using the Google Maps Engine user interface on Google itself, and doesn't appear to have any actual programming aspect involved with it. As I explained in the comments on your your question, just because I create something on a site that eventually gets implemented into a program or design doesn't mean the use of that site is programming-related or on-topic here.

Since your question seems to be more about using a web application rather than about programming, it *may* be on-topic over at [Web Apps SE](http://webapps.stackexchange.com). As always, read their help center before asking a question there.

Comment: Hey I appreciate your feedback, that made things pretty clear. Thank you.